# Stacked histogram from unequal vectors in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have 2 different vectors:

```
> x$layer
 [1] 0.40000000 0.26153846 0.28305235 0.21058573 0.37593985 0.29437229
 [7] 0.26306306 0.50982801 0.22368421 0.55715871 0.21241830 0.22757940
[13] 0.09388298 0.31101190 0.36363636 0.11277670 0.41382576 0.23955992
[19] 0.33333333 0.12829324 0.40106952 0.56818182 0.22222222 0.21591746
[25] 0.17647059 0.46190476 0.19523810 0.11502831 0.16916558 0.23270440
[31] 0.17787570 0.47401575

> un$layer
  [1] -0.260869565  0.128649184  0.068607069  0.071428571 -0.166666667
  [6]  0.311011905  0.363636364  0.021739130  0.110389610  0.112776699
 [11]  0.136088710  0.000000000  0.076086957  0.101260937  0.238095238
 [16] -0.466666667 -0.058823529  0.000000000  0.029411765  0.033799534
 [21]  0.060728745 -0.188636364 -0.055555556  0.067910091  0.413825758
 [26]  0.239559920  0.000000000  0.071693989  0.000000000  0.000000000
 [31]  0.000000000  0.014473684 -0.316239316 -0.006666667  0.080000000
 [36]  0.051282051  0.333333333 -0.042553191  0.128293242 -0.042218593
 [41]  0.043262411  0.022435897  0.401069519  0.568181818  0.091419407
 [46] -0.032258065  0.000000000  0.000000000 -0.241258741 -0.088993711
 [51]  0.000000000  0.033043478 -0.044771242 -0.402777778 -0.058823529
```

I want to plot a stacked histogram of 'x' and 'un' with a 0.1 interval with 2 different colors-

```
h=hist(b$layer, xlab='n',
       breaks=seq(-0.6,0.6,by=0.1), ylim=c(0,40), xaxt='n', main="", col='blue')
h=hist(un$layer, xlab='n', beside=FALSE,
       breaks=seq(-0.6,0.6,by=0.1), ylim=c(0,40), xaxt='n', main="", col='red', add=TRUE)
axis(side=1, at=seq(-0.6,0.6,by=0.1), labels=seq(-0.6,0.6,0.1))
```

how to plot 'un' at the top of 'b'? Looks like the argument: beside =FALSE doesn't work as it does for bar plots. Though I'd prefer doing it with the base package, I don't mind using ggplot2, reshape etc. if that's easier.

Comment: are you ignoring the warning that beside is not a graphical parameter? hist does not have beside as an argument. maybe you are thinking of barplot? why are we not allowed to mention ggplot or reshape?

Comment: I tried ggplot2, it requires at least one value for each bin, so doesn't work. I'm not a fan of ggplot2, working with base package gives the ease of modifying every bits in a figure.

Comment: if you want to specify intervals and plot two groups, you're not thinking of a histogram. A histogram is specifically designed to estimate the density of a continuous variable. It sounds like you just want to compare counts between two groups which is really a barplot.

Comment: yes you can say it a barplot, but sometimes each bar of barplot is 100% which I don't want to show. I want to compare the counts in particular. To make a barplot I also have to modify the data and divide into different intervals first to make my matrix which is painstaking. So I used the word histogram, if you like to call it a barplot, its fine.@MrFlick

Comment: youre quite cheeky for a guy asking for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this. First, here's your data in a more friendly copy/pasteable format

```
xlayer <-
c(0.4, 0.26153846, 0.28305235, 0.21058573, 0.37593985, 0.29437229, 
0.26306306, 0.50982801, 0.22368421, 0.55715871, 0.2124183, 0.2275794, 
0.09388298, 0.3110119, 0.36363636, 0.1127767, 0.41382576, 0.23955992, 
0.33333333, 0.12829324, 0.40106952, 0.56818182, 0.22222222, 0.21591746, 
0.17647059, 0.46190476, 0.1952381, 0.11502831, 0.16916558, 0.2327044, 
0.1778757, 0.47401575)
unlayer <-
c(-0.260869565, 0.128649184, 0.068607069, 0.071428571, -0.166666667, 
0.311011905, 0.363636364, 0.02173913, 0.11038961, 0.112776699, 
0.13608871, 0, 0.076086957, 0.101260937, 0.238095238, -0.466666667, 
-0.058823529, 0, 0.029411765, 0.033799534, 0.060728745, -0.188636364, 
-0.055555556, 0.067910091, 0.413825758, 0.23955992, 0, 0.071693989, 
0, 0, 0, 0.014473684, -0.316239316, -0.006666667, 0.08, 0.051282051, 
0.333333333, -0.042553191, 0.128293242, -0.042218593, 0.043262411, 
0.022435897, 0.401069519, 0.568181818, 0.091419407, -0.032258065, 
0, 0, -0.241258741, -0.088993711, 0, 0.033043478, -0.044771242, 
-0.402777778, -0.058823529)
```

Now I combine the data into a single data.frame and cut the data.

```
dd <- rbind(data.frame(layer="x", value=xlayer), data.frame(layer="un", value=unlayer))
```

And then divide into your specific cuts

```
mybreaks<-seq(-0.6,0.6,by=0.1)
mybreaknames <- sprintf("%0.2f",diff(mybreaks)/2+mybreaks[-length(mybreaks)])
dd$group = cut(dd$value, breaks=mybreaks)
```

And now I plot the data

```
barplot(with(dd, table(layer,group)), beside=F, names.arg=mybreaknames)
```

And that gives the following plot

[image: stacked histogram]

EDIT:

Here's a version with perhaps a better x-axis

```
mybreaks<-seq(-0.6,0.6,by=0.1)
dd$group = cut(dd$value, breaks=mybreaks)

xx<-barplot(with(dd, table(layer,group)), beside=F, xaxt="n", legend=levels(dd$layer))
ats<-xx[-length(xx)]+diff(xx)/2
ats<-c(2*ats[1]-ats[2], ats, 2*ats[length(ats)]-ats[length(ats)-1])
axis(1, at=ats, labels=sprintf("%.1f",mybreaks))
```

[image: continuous x-axis stacked bar plot]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `ggplot` solution (using MrFlick's nicely formatted data)

```
library(ggplot2)
dd <- data.frame(obs = c(xlayer, unlayer),
                 dist = c(rep("x", length(xlayer)), rep("un", length(unlayer))))


# Stacked, as requested
ggplot(dd, aes(x = obs, fill = dist)) +
    geom_bar(position = "stack", binwidth = 0.1)
```

[image]

You'll notice the order of the stacking is opposite from Mr Flick's answer, it could be modified by reordering the `dist` factor.

```
# Nice and easy to switch to an overlapped-with-transparency alternative
ggplot(dd, aes(x = obs, fill = dist)) +
    geom_bar(position = "identity", binwidth = 0.1, alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

I find this one a little easier to read, and stacking order doesn't matter.